# Não visualiza Dominio meu site

Tags: wordpress, apache, linux

montei um servidor caseiro ( debian Linux + no-ip+ apache + mysql + wordpress + clud dns ).

meu problema é que :

ele acessa www.prensanuble.cl MAS quando eu tento acessar qualquer link do site deixa de mostrar o dominio ou seja:

http://www.prensanuble.cl/meu_diretorio ( deveria mostrar assim no browser) 
http://prensanuble.ddns.net/meu_diretorio (esta mostrando assim, ou seja , não mostra o dominio e sim o NO-IP)

Podem me dar uma ajuda por favor? tenho acesso ao servidor completo.
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Configuraste corretamente o nome do servidor no Wordpress no arquivo `wp-config`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, aguarde 1 min... vejo na hoira isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://prensanuble.ddns.net' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://prensanuble.ddns.net/html' );

Comment: Acredito que esse é o problema, nunca utilizei WP antes, mas acredito fielmente que `WP_SITEURL` é utilizado para gerar as URL no corpo da página e, por isso, seus links internos aparecem com este domínio.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , me ajudou muito solucionou um 99% dos Link.
no Theme tem um link chamado Inicio que ainda manda ao no-ip...
estou reiniciando o server pra ver se modifica algo.

Comment: Irei converter o comentário em resposta para que possa indicar o tópico como resolvido.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, muiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiito obrigado cara !!!!
Deus te abençoe muitooooo, valeu pela ajuda....
Tenha ótimo final de semana :D

Answer (score 1):

Como esclarecido nos comentários, você manteve a configuração `WP_SITEURL` com o domínio do *NO-IP*:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'prensanuble.ddns.net'); 
define('WP_SITEURL', 'prensanuble.ddns.net/html');
```

A configuração `WP_SITEURL` é utilizada internamente pelo WordPress para gerar as URL no corpo da página então, independente do domínio que está utilizando para acessá-la, as URLs serão geradas sob o domínio especificado.

Basta alterar para:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'www.prensanuble.cl');
```

Que deve funcionar como esperado.